# Как при подключении по SSH указать нужный ключ?

Tags: ssh

В каталоге лежит несколько ключей для разных серверов. Можно ли при подключении указать какой тип ключа использовать, например что-то типа такого:

```
ssh <username>@<ip_addres> -name <key_name>
```

Comment: Опция `-i identity_file`.